# how to autofill Infopath dropdown field using Jquery on page load?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, jquery, dropdown

I am using Infopath and SharePoint 2013, and trying to set fields in the Infopath form when the page loads all the text fields populate fine but none of the drop-down field types do. I am assuming that this is happening because the options don't loaded when the page does. can anyone help me remedy this?

```
 $(function() {
    $('#ctl00_ctl43_g_e_FormControl0_V1_I1_D5').val('apple');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably worked this out by now. If trying to autopopulate the dropdown with jquery, you would use something similar to:

```
$(function() {
$("#ctl00_ctl43_g_e_FormControl0_V1_I1_D5").append('<option value="apple">apple</option>');
};
```